# Как ускорить запрос ORDER BY (status = 1) DESC, id DESC?

Tags: mysql

Запрос вида:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY (status = 1), id DESC
```

из-за **(status = 1)** получается не используются индексы при сортировки и выполнение тупит

суть запроса: вывести сначала узеров со статусом 1, потом все остальные с сортировкой по ID

есть идеи чем можно заменить **ORDER BY (status = 1)**, что бы работало побыстрее ?

Comment: Если `status`  начинается с 1, то можно просто `ORDER BY status`

Comment: не подходит, остальные юзеры должны быть отсортированы по ID, независимо от статуса

Comment: Сделать union из двух запросов?

Comment: пробовал, почему-то тоже долго отрабатывает, если использовать 2 разных запроса, отрабатывает в сумме быстрее чем один через UNION или ORDER BY (status = 1)

Comment: Можно создать виртуальное вычисляемое поле и индекс по нему. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=79f4a23081c17730efccf6a2122492bf